# how to use input tag into table - table td full size of column

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

i'm trying to use input tags into table without any border to the input tag

```html
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr class="bg-info">
                <th>first name</th>
                <th>last name</th>
                <th>college</th>
                <th>department</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

i want to remove this [image] the blank lines , and make input tag full size of the column ? is it possible please , trying to implement something like this

**bootstrap 4**

thank you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the default padding foreach cell and default border of form-control

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
/* remove the padding of cell */
table.table tr td {
  padding:0;
}


/* remove the border of input */
input.form-control, input.form-control:focus {
  border:0;
  box-shadow:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-info">
      <th>first name</th>
      <th>last name</th>
      <th>college</th>
      <th>department</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```